# Flutter stack of cards

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to create a stack of cards, superimposed, and offset of each other to visualize multiple versions of a card.

[image]

I have tried putting cards inside cards, but do not find a way to offset them.
I also tried using the stack class with no luck.

Anyone know how i can achieve this effect?

Comment: Please show some of the code you have tried. It may help in answering the question. See: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As @P.Moloney suggested, as of now it's impossible to answer your question. I'd specifically recommend the [Minimal,. Complete and Verfiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the How to ask segment.

Comment: I tried using:

return new Container(
    child: new Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: new ListCard(
            koblingsordre: list[index],
         ),
     ),
);

This gives me two cards on top of eachother but with no option for the offsett as in the image.

I also tried using the stack class but with no effect close to what i want.

Sorry this is a comment, i dont got enough points to edit, says i cant upload the image again...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were going in the right direction with Stack - you just had to figure out how to offset the widget. The best way to do this for the 'top' of the stack is to use padding, but you don't want to have to specify the size of each of the cards... it's much better if the stack grows/shrinks based on the content which is actually being shown.

To that end, you can use Positioned with all of the sizes specified for the cards. That will make sure that they grow to the appropriate size, without making the stack resize or having to specify each of their sizes.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              StackOfCards(
                child: Container(height: 100.0),
                num: 5,
              ),
              StackOfCards(
                child: Container(height: 100.0),
                num: 4,
              ),
              StackOfCards(
                child: Container(height: 100.0),
                num: 3,
              ),
              StackOfCards(
                child: Container(height: 100.0),
                num: 2,
              ),
              StackOfCards(
                child: Container(height: 100.0),
                num: 1,
              )
            \],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StackOfCards extends StatelessWidget {
  final int num;
  final Widget child;
  final double offset;

  const StackOfCards({Key key, int num = 1, @required this.child, this.offset = 10.0})
      : this.num = num > 0 ? num : 1,
        assert(offset != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Stack(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
            num - 1,
            (val) => Positioned(
                bottom: val * offset,
                left: val * offset,
                top: (num - val - 1) * offset,
                right: (num - val - 1) * offset,
                child: Card(child: Container()))).toList()
          ..add(
            Padding(
              child: Card(child: child),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: (num - 1) * offset, left: (num - 1) * offset),
            ),
          ),
      );
}
```

Hmmm... I guess that build function could probably be explained a bit. What I'm doing is using a generated list to iterate from 0..(num cards - 1) and calculating the appropriate offsets for each Positioned widget (each of which contains an essentially empty card).

Then this gets made from an iterable to a list with `.toList()`, but doesn't have the top card yet... so I do an inline add (I'm sure there's a better word for that, but I don't know it) of the Padding widget that has the appropriate offsets and contains the child. The `..add` just makes it so that I can do it in one line - it returns the list instead of void as `.add` would. Yay for dart =)!

I made it a little bit flexible, but you could go further and define the offset as two parameters, make it so that you can go different directions etc. Anyways, the code results in this:

[image: Screenshot of cards]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best approach but according to the sample you posted in the comment you can align it with a Stack and Padding:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 8.0),
      child: Card(
          child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Text("Content"),
        ),
      )),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
      child: Card(
          child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Text("Content"),
        ),
      )),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Which will look like this:

[image]

You can then customize it with setting different paddings etc.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, with this answer you have to make sure you manually set the 'bottom' cards to have the exact same size as the top card (which @Bostrot got around by simply using the same content). While that does work, it's not really optimal.