# flutter UI: How to Make card like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

this is my ui card

[image]

How to make like this ui?

Answer (score 0):

Try below answers on Stack Overflow hope its help to you.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187547/13997210) by [@rmtmckenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2927226/rmtmckenzie)

Or refer [**`flutter_tindercard`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard) package